# Grails not including plugins with war (jquery-date-time-picker:0.2.0)

Tags: jquery, grails, war

when i run application via grails run-app everything is fine but when i run grails run-war my jquery related plugins seem to be gone....  What am i screwing up?  thanks in advance for all the help.

buildconfig.groovy:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
        // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
        //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

        // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
        test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
        // configure settings for the run-app JVM
        run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
        // configure settings for the run-war JVM
        war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
        // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
        console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
        compile "commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3"
        runtime "org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1201-jdbc41"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:2.4.3"
        compile ':jquery-date-time-picker:0.2.0'
        compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.4"
        compile ":jquery-datatables:1.7.5"
        compile ":csv:0.3.1"
        compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC5'
        compile ':quartz:1.0.1'



        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"


        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

my application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js.
//
// Any JavaScript file within this directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// You're free to add application-wide JavaScript to this file, but it's generally better 
// to create separate JavaScript files as needed.
//
//= require jquery
//= require js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom
//= require jquery-ui-timepicker-addon
//= require jquery.dataTables
//= require_tree .
//= require_self

if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
    (function($) {
        $('#spinner').ajaxStart(function() {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }).ajaxStop(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    })(jQuery);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".dateTimePicker" ).datepicker();
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    // bind DataTable on table ID
    $('#defaultDataTable').dataTable( {
        /* to increase the process and speed for loading data from server
         * (check more properties if needed )
         */
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bDeferRender": true
    });

    $('#aircraftTable').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [4,5],
                "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [4,5]
            }
        ] } );

    bindDataTable();
    chosen();
    bindDateTimePicker();
});


/* Chosen (select box - chosen) */
function chosen(){
    if($('.chosen-select').length > 0){
        $('.chosen-select').each(function(){
            var $el = $(this);
            var search = ($el.attr("data-nosearch") === "true") ? true : false,
                opt = {};
            if(search) opt.disable_search_threshold = 9999999;
            $el.chosen(opt);
        });
    }
}
function bindDateTimePicker(){
    /* date picker */
    if($('.datepick').length > 0){
        $('.datepick').datepicker();
    }
    /* date range picker */
    if($('.daterangepick').length > 0){
        $('.daterangepick').daterangepicker();
    }
    /* time picker */
    if($('.timepick').length > 0){
        $('.timepick').timepicker({
            defaultTime: 'current',
            minuteStep: 1,
            disableFocus: true,
            template: 'dropdown'
        });
    }
}
```

my main.gsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title><g:layoutTitle default="Grails"/></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="${assetPath(src: 'favicon.ico')}" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="${assetPath(src: 'apple-touch-icon.png')}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="${assetPath(src: 'apple-touch-icon-retina.png')}">
    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
    <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
    <g:layoutHead/>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Base</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><g:link controller="ScheduledEvent">Events</g:link></li>
            <li><g:link controller="ScheduledEvent">ADS Record List</g:link></li>
            <sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Admin <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><g:link controller="ScheduledEvent">Customer</g:link></li>
                        %{--                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li class="dropdown-header">Security:</li>
                                                <li><g:link controller="ScheduledEvent">Role</g:link></li>
                                                <li><g:link controller="ScheduledEvent">User</g:link></li>
                                                <li><g:link controller="ScheduledEvent">User/Role Assignment</g:link></li>--}%
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </sec:ifAnyGranted>
        </ul>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right"  method="POST"action="${resource(file: 'j_spring_security_check')}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" name='j_username' id='username'/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" name='j_password' id='password'/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
            </form>
            </sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
            <sec:ifLoggedIn>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><g:link controller="logout">[ Log Out ]</g:link></li>
                </ul>
            </sec:ifLoggedIn>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
<g:layoutBody/>
<div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>

<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;"><g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

also noticed the  info changes in the war
non war:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Scheduled Event List</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/base/assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/base/assets/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/base/assets/apple-touch-icon-retina.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/base/assets/bootstrap.css?compile=false"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/base/assets/custom.css?compile=false"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/base/assets/jquery.dataTables.css?compile=false"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/base/assets/application.css?compile=false"  />

    <script src="/base/assets/jquery-1.11.3.min.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/base/assets/jquery-ui.min.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/base/assets/jquery.dataTables.min.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/base/assets/affix.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/base/assets/alert.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/base/assets/button.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/base/assets/carousel.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/base/assets/collapse.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/base/assets/dropdown.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/base/assets/modal.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/base/assets/popover.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/base/assets/scrollspy.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/base/assets/tab.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/base/assets/tooltip.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/base/assets/transition.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/base/assets/application.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript" ></script>


    <meta name="layout" content="main">



</head>
```

and the head from the war

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Scheduled Event List</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/base/assets/favicon-9ef27019cc7a636e29ecc851528f716e.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/base/assets/apple-touch-icon-c915103363017d14cea9c2a46ea12166.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/base/assets/apple-touch-icon-retina-21d524e96ee946f16c9b8fb4ea0c3f6e.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/base/assets/application-05d0813af24ff9275b9df9f05c1db91d.css"/>
    <script src="/base/assets/application-e2bb20b8d7511fca0d3d6620077bcc41.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

    <meta name="layout" content="main">



</head>
```